# Installing Snipmate with Pathogen vim

Tags: vim, snipmate, pathogen

I attempted to install Snipmate in vim via Pathogen, by:

```
cd ~/Dropbox/vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate
cd vim-snipmate
git clone https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets.git
```

(My vim repository is in Dropbox, with my ~/.vimrc reading:

```
set runtimepath+=~/Dropbox/vim
source ~/Dropbox/vim/vimrc.vim
```

)

However nothing happens when I press tab. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? Based on other blogs/questions, I have already tried moving the snippets directory to ~/.vim/ and other locations, but to no avail. I also have "filetype plugin on". So I'm pretty stumped. Am I being stupid here?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try another syncing method than Dropbox. It's convenient, that's for sure, but I had a few problems with broken files which led me to use [insert your favorite VCS here] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SnipMate makes use of the *after directory* to define its mappings (to ensure that no other plugin overrides them). Therefore, you need to add that directory hierarchy to `'runtimepath'`, too:

```
set runtimepath+=~/Dropbox/vim,~/Dropbox/vim/after
```